# Verdana doesn't want to display

Tags: html, css, fonts

A rudimentary piece of code indicating the font:

```
<td style="padding-top:5px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:9pt;   color:#f0e9e2; text-align:justify">
```

**Internet Explorer** and **Google Chrome** doesn't want to display the **Verdana** font, it displays an **Arial** font. If I put some other font instead of the **Verdana** font, it displays that, no problem, it displays the **Verdana** font higher up in the page.

What can the problem possibly be?

Thanks.

Comment: Try wrapping it in single quotes ('). e.g `font-family:'Verdana', Arial, sans-serif;`

Comment: as far as I can see, that code should work. Have you tried firebug or similar tools to see which CSS rules affect your text? maybe there are surrounding elements with !important rules or elements inside the <td> with own class / style? (or just a simple typo somewhere?)

Comment: Check your `DOCTYPE` declaration, if a browser enters the quirks mode, some things will display a little bit different.

Comment: If none of the above works, i'd suggest adding more code or a link to the project etc..

Answer (score 1):

Well, I suppose you're developing some kind of mail design since you're putting the styles inline?

Have you tried just adding an '!important' to your code?

```
<td style="padding-top:5px; font-family:Verdana !important; font-size:9pt;   color:#f0e9e2; text-align:justify">
```

Yes it gets even more bloated, but as far as e-mail marketing goes, you don't really have much room for cleanliness...

Comment: I think you're missing the point.  He was using that snippet as an example, not to show his coding style.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you cant see any change in the font is because you are using the td tag.

I checked this in a fiddle.

Here is the first exampe: [FIDDLE 1](http://jsfiddle.net/Jzq9k/1/)

Here is the second example: [FIDDLE 2](http://jsfiddle.net/Jzq9k/2/)

The code is the same in both the examples:

```
<td style="padding-top:5px; font-family:Verdana, Arial, sans-serif; font-size:16pt;   color:#f0e9e2; text-align:justify">HELLO WORLD</td>
```

However if you see in the second example, I have enclosed the td tag in a table. Only after we do this do the attributes get applied to the td tag.

**EDIT:** Explanation:The td tag is used to define a data cell that is used within a table. Hence the td tag had to be nested within a tr tag which in turn has to be nested within a table, since both td and tr are table elements.

Comment: No the td tag is nested inside a table with its tr tags & everything, all the tags closed all nicely as they should be. The doctype is strict --> & there's no other class / style rules in the td tag or the rest of the table, its just a straight forward piece of text -- the tag I posted above is the whole tag for it

Comment: OK, I've figured out what's happening. I'm changing an old site from transitional [EmulateIE7(!) don't ask!] to strict. The browser IS displaying the Verdana but the new browsers are rendering the Verdana differently from the IE7 & I just presumed it was the Arial because it looks so different. Sorry about the false alarm & thanks so much again for all the advice.

Answer (score -1):

Use this,

```
.title{

font-family:verdana;
}
```

it works!I try in Google Chrome and I

Comment: No, the td tag is nested inside a table with its tr tags & everything. The doctype is strict & there's no other class / style rules in the td tag or the rest of the table, its just a straightforward piece of text, the tag above is the whole tag for it. The weirdest thing is that it doesn't have a problem displaying another font, it's just the Verdana, never seen anything like it. I'll check for typos again & try the single quotes. If that doesn't work I'll upload the page -- it's not live at the moment. Thanks very much for all the suggestions!